# D3.js CodeFlower Image as circle background

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I am using CodeFlower built upon D3.js. I want to show an image as a background instead of arbitrary colors, and i successfully did that using SVG Patterns.

[DEMO FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/voidSO/2DUy9/46/)

```
  // Enter any new nodes
  this.node.enter().append('defs')
        .append('pattern')
            .attr('id', function(d) { return (d.id+"-icon-img");}) // just create a unique id (id comes from the json)
            .attr('patternUnits', 'userSpaceOnUse')
            .attr('width', 80)
            .attr('height', 80)
            .append("svg:image")
                .attr("xlink:xlink:href", function(d) { return (d.icon);}) // "icon" is my image url. It comes from json too. The double xlink:xlink is a necessary hack (first "xlink:" is lost...).
                .attr("x", 0)
                .attr("y", 0)
                .attr("height", 80)
                .attr("width", 80)
                .attr("preserveAspectRatio", "xMinYMin slice");

  this.node.enter().append('svg:circle')
    .attr("class", "node CodeFlowerNode")
    .classed('directory', function(d) { return (d._children || d.children) ? 1 : 0; })
    .attr("r", function(d) { return d.children ? 3.5 : Math.pow(d.size, 2/5) || 1; })
    .style("fill", function(d) { return ("url(#"+d.id+"-icon-img)");})
    /* .style("fill", function color(d) {
      return "hsl(" + parseInt(360 / total * d.id, 10) + ",90%,70%)";
    })*/
    .call(this.force.drag)
    .on("click", this.click.bind(this))
    .on("mouseover", this.mouseover.bind(this))
    .on("mouseout", this.mouseout.bind(this));
```

The problem i am seeing is the image is not centrally aligned in the circle it is kind of tile layout composed of 4 images.

[image]

How can i make its position center and covering the circle nicely.

[DEMO FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/voidSO/2DUy9/46/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to change the way you define your pattern.  You should define it with respect to the element it is being applied to.  So leave `patternUnits` at the default of `objectBoundingBox`, and set the `width` and `height` to `1`.

Then you need to also set the `patternContentUnits` to `objectBoundingBox` also, and give the `<image>` the same size (width and height of `1`).

```
  this.node.enter().append('defs')
        .append('pattern')
            .attr('id', function(d) { return (d.id+"-icon");})  
            .attr('width', 1)
            .attr('height', 1)
            .attr('patternContentUnits', 'objectBoundingBox')
            .append("svg:image")
                .attr("xlink:xlink:href", function(d) { return (d.icon);})
                .attr("height", 1)
                .attr("width", 1)
                .attr("preserveAspectRatio", "xMinYMin slice");
```

[Demo fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/2DUy9/47/)

Comment: Can you help me with one more little thing.. The circle is currently transparent, how can i fill in some color to the area which is inside the circle but outside the image?

Comment: It's working for me on Chrome but I can't make it work on Safari/Firefox. I always have a black circle instead of a circle with the image inside. Thanks for any help.