# Add background-image to SVG circle

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I want to add a background-image to my SVG circle. But I can't get it to work. Here is what I have so far:

EDIT AGAIN:

Now this is what I have. And it almost works:

```
    // SVG -> G with margin convention
    var svg = d3.select('.clock').append('svg');
    var g = svg.append('g')
      .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ',' + margin.top + ')');

    // Clock Face
    var face = g.append('g')
      .datum(clock)
      .attr('transform', 'translate(' + w / 2 + ',' + r + ')');

    const svgInner = face.append('svg')
    .attr({
      height: function (d) { return (d.r * 2); },
      width: function (d) { return (d.r * 2); },
    });

    svgInner.append('circle')
    .attr({
    r: function (d) { return d.r; },
    fill: 'url(#image)',
    height: function (d) { return (d.r * 2); },
    width: function (d) { return (d.r * 2); },
    });

    svgInner.append('defs')
    .append('pattern')
    .attr('id', 'image')
    .attr('width', function (d) { return (d.r * 2); })
    .attr('height', function (d) { return (d.r * 2); })
    .attr('patternContentUnits', 'objectBoundingBox')
    .append('image').attr({
      transform: 'translate(-63, -63)',
    })
    .attr({
      height: function (d) { return (d.r * 2); },
      width: function (d) { return (d.r * 2); },
      'xlink:href': 'image.jpg',
    });
```

The only thing I have to fix is the position of the image(it should be in the circle, but it is moved to the bottom right, as you can see in the picture.[image]

Comment: This will answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32221296/d3-js-codeflower-image-as-circle-background

Comment: @Thinker I edited my post. Could you take another look?

Comment: can you please post your complete code ?

Comment: Can you specify exactly what *"doesn't work"*. What's the expected outcome?

Comment: I updated again. Thanks for your help so far guys